# Does Garbage Collection delete objects before addShutdownHook executes?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I've been using this code: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/runtime_addshutdownhook.htm - to save critical data upon termination. However, I get an error message:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This occurs when I try to return an instance of an object, the process of which was terminated. To clarify, the data I am returning has been initiated, i.e. it has some default values. So, it should at least return the default values, but not the error. My only explanation would be to think it's all because of GC.

Should I use `try{}catch{}finally{}` to save critical data? Or is `addShutdownHook` supposed to work just fine with the method I am describing, so I should either provide more information on the code or try to find an error in my code?

EDIT 1:

Using this as my main:

```
public class Main {
private static Object objectInstance;
// a class that extends thread that is to be called when the program is exiting
static class Message extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Object " + objectInstance.getTemporary()
                + " " + objectInstance.isExists());
        System.out.println("Bye.");
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // register Message as shutdown hook
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Message());
        // print the state of the program
        System.out.println("Program is starting...");
        // call the object instances
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Next...");
            objectInstance = new Object(i);
        }
        // print that the program is closing
        System.out.println("Program is closing...");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And this as my object:

```
public class Object {
private boolean exists = false;
private int temporary;
public Object(int temporary) {
    this.temporary = temporary;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        // upon completion
        exists = true;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
// returns to main
public boolean isExists() {
    return exists;
}
// return the index
public int getTemporary() {
    return temporary;
}
}
```

Apparently, if you terminate when the first instance of the object is in the process, it will throw the error I am talking about. Afterwards, say on the third instance of the object, it will print the information on the previous object (second in this case). It isn't saving the latest instance. Should I create an empty initialiser, and then the processing? Apparently, it does not save the instance in the main because of that.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Normally, a NPE means your reference to the object is null, regardless of whether it has been cleaned up by the GC.  And normally, the GC won't clean something up if you have any references to it.

Comment: @SteveSmith to fix this error, I created a global variable in the Main class, `private static ObjectRef object;`. When the object is initialised, it is assigned to this global variable. So, everytime a new instance is initialised, it is changing the global reference too. The global variable is then used by `addShutdownHook `, where the object is accessed through `object.getData()`, but produces the error above. 

My understanding is that the global variable contains the object instance, therefore there must not be any errors for the NPE.
I'll try to recreate the same error in smaller code.

Comment: The first thing to learn, is that exchanging data between different threads requires thread safe constructs. Second, no neither does the garbage collector run when the JVM terminates (why should it do that?) nor does the garbage collector ever set ordinary variables to `null`. And whatever critical operation you have in mind, you should always try to complete it as soon as possible instead of hoping that a shutdown hook will eventually complete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixes my issue. For main:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     System.out.println("Next...");
     objectInstance = new Object(i);
     System.out.println("Initialised.");
     objectInstance.method();
}
```

For object:

```
public Object(int temporary) {
    this.temporary = temporary;
}
public void method() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        // upon completion
        exists = true;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: It looks like your problem was caused because the program was exiting while the constructor was running.  Now that you've moved the `Thread.sleep(3000);` to a method, the constructor is virtually instant, and so the object will exist.

Comment: Yes! Thought that constructor was saved as soon as it was initiated. Thanks for the explanation!